# Одновременный запуск и синхронизация потоков в Android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Всем привет.

В приложении есть таймер обратного отсчёта, который запускает Chronometer по завершении:

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, countDownInterval)
{
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        countDownTimer.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished + 1000) / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish()
    {
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.start();
    }
}.start();
```

И метроном:

```
private void playMetronome()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            metronome.play();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Я хочу запустить метроном вместе с таймером обратного отсчёта и продолжить воспроизводить метроном во время работы хронометра. Сейчас при попытке выполнить подобный код идёт рассинхрон метронома и хронометра после нескольких секунд.

Подскажите, каким образом можно синхронизировать работу обратного отсчёта, метронома и хронометра?

Comment: делать все в одном потоке или например через Handler

Comment: Посмотри в английском StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927724/making-precise-android-metronome

Comment: Пробовал сделать такой метроном, но он сильно сбивается при запуске. Сейчас остановился на реализации метронома из примера: https://masterex.github.io/archive/2012/05/28/android-audio-synthesis.html
Но синхронизация с таймером также сбивается.